# How to Change column data type from boolean to varchar(50)?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How do I change data type of a column from boolean to `varchar(50)` in snowflake?

`OTCONTROLLABLE BOOLEAN` in the following example to `OTCONTROLLABLE varchar(50)`

```sql
create or replace TABLE ORIGINATIONUNRECOGNIZEDREVENUE_OTCN030 (
   YEAR VARCHAR(50),
   MONTH VARCHAR(50),
   OTCONTROLLABLE BOOLEAN);
```

Comment: Hi Neeraj, if any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Neeraj - you can run a CTAS statement to create a new table and then swap the tables.

Documentation to walk you through the CTAS here;

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/create-table.html#variant-syntax

Swap statement;

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/alter-table.html#syntax

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend the approach that @bstora suggested but here is another option too for reference:

1. Backup the table you're working on
2. Add a new `varchar` column to the table
3. Copy the values from the `boolean` column to the new `varchar` column with an `update` statement
4. Drop the old `boolean` column
5. Rename the varchar column to have the same name as the dropped `boolean` column

```sql
-- Setup example table
create or replace temporary table public.example_table (
   bool_col boolean
);

-- Insert some sample values
insert overwrite into public.example_table values (1), (0);

-- Create a new varchar column to hold the boolean values as varchar
alter table public.example_table add column temp_varchar_col varchar(50);

-- Copy all of the values from the boolean column to the new varchar column
update public.example_table set temp_varchar_col = bool_col;

-- Check the data looks okay in the new column
select * from public.example_table;

-- Drop the old boolean-typed column
alter table public.example_table drop column bool_col;

-- Rename the varchar column to the same name as the dropped boolean-typed column
alter table public.example_table rename column temp_varchar_col to bool_col;

-- Check everything looks okay
select * from public.example_table;
```

The advantage of the swap-table approach as mentioned by bstora is that users will never see a table with two columns and it's probably quicker too.

Comment: I almost put up a similar answer. This can be helpful especially if the table is very large or active.